# Checking chrome url autocomplete prabability stats

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete, statistics

I want to see the probability stats that chrome has for certain keywords I type in the ommnibox, but I can't remember the command used to do it.

What I mean is, when I type "twi" it gives me a list of the most visited urls that have that keyword, but the first one is my twitter profile url, because that's usually what I pick, so it increases the probability of that choice.

There's a command you type in the omnibox that takes you to a page where it shows all the url suggestions for certain keywords and their probability to be the right choice. I've used it once, so I know it's possible, does anyone knows what it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To view the omnibox stored data**

You can view all the omnibox data by navigating to the following link:

```
chrome://predictors/
```

The below command also lets you test out and see partial results

```
chrome://omnibox/
```

**Deleting an individual entry from the omnibox**

Type in the first few letters, like `Twi` and then select the link using your keyboard's arrow keys then hold down <kbd>shift</kbd> and hit <kbd>delete</kbd>. to remove that link.

Comment: Yes I know, but I don't want to remove links, I just want to see the data it has about the urls and their respective weight related to different keywords.

Comment: Sorry Miguel. Edited my post to add a method of seeing the omnibox stored data.

Comment: No problem, you were almost there actually. If you go to 'chrome://chrome-urls/' it gives you a list of all those hidden commands, and one of them is 'chrome://predictors/' which is exactly what I was looking.

Comment: Updated my post to make it more relevant. Thanks Miguel, that's a great tip.